# Erro ao testar data source SQL Server no servidor WebSphere 8.5 com java 8 dá o seguinte erro:

Tags: java, ssl, datasource

Erro ao testar a conexão do data source SQL Server no servidor WebSphere 8.5 com java 8 dá o seguinte erro:

The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "No appropriate protocol, may be no appropriate cipher suite specified or protocols are deactivated". DSRA0010E: Estado de SQL = 08S01, Código de Erro = 0.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei alterar as configurações de confiabilidade do was, porém nada aconteceu.
OBS.: Esse meu WebSphere foi copiado de outra máquina, que também está apresentando o mesmo problema. E só conseguimos testar os datasources do DB2, mas pra sql server dá erro.